# Disable tooltip labels being truncated/increasing tooltip character limit when using vega-lite

Tags: javascript, kibana, vega-lite

Im creating a visualization in kibana using vega-lite, but I suppose this applies anywhere. Is there a way in vega-lite to disable, or at least increase the character length of the tooltip so that it is not truncated? I can't find any documentation or links about this. Thanks.
The following is a rough example. I'd like the tooltip to show the full length of 'aaaaabbbcccc' instead of it being automatically truncated to 'aaabbbc...'

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC", "b": 28},
      {"a": "B", "b": 55},
      {"a": "C", "b": 43},
      {"a": "D", "b": 91},
      {"a": "E", "b": 81},
      {"a": "F", "b": 53},
      {"a": "G", "b": 19},
      {"a": "H", "b": 87},
      {"a": "I", "b": 52}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "a", "type": "ordinal"},
    "y": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"},
    "tooltip": [
      {"field": "a", "type": "ordinal"},
      {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"}
    ]
  },
   "config": {
    "view": {"stroke": "transparent"},
    "axis": {
      "labelColor": "#98A2B3",
      "grid": false,
      "labelLimit": 100
    }
  }
}
```

[Online editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoAWOgCtY3AHaQANOCgATdHkw5QECJAroxrZLGxgA2hsNhgkPVACCb9x89eAQr7-+A3wBhENCw8LUodisAJgAOAF91ewhHZ0hvSMhonABWXKS7QzSrSCCsnLBpAGZClIcnUoARCqsATgBGOpSSnEgAUVacOK7knsa+gDEhsFzasfteqABxGY627sWJqAAJGbiAdk3i7cgASRncmISigF0NbsgMACcAa1L2dGe1DUhkJXg3E0jCU1CsBkMkAAHuDIAAzRjIMSaUqYVRQPAAT0IyFK3GewKUpkgx0gmNhCKRKL60XRkCxONKAEdWOglHhmDpGFQSQsMdxuGIOYQrLZ6o5KcjUVkGbi+vjCcTjql4YipTSZdi5VAWWyOboOTybvZ7hBNpBAUoEWD9EVjIiAO6w2B4Z7cV7a+nPNmwQhff54Xl29BQxiWW31SBidDsJFBQX40oAYjacRcMW81R+keoz0Y1LAcNMsGQfKM0djYgAMoxUMwrB0AAyNorGsA3BJAA)

Answer (score 1):

I tried [manipulating the graph](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoDSACCFy1es2AQvYcOAEracApF24AitgDJuAZXdbL19HRwBhKOiY2MUQJjQAJgAOAF8FEzQQW3jE1ABWAoys9Ai8tDEAZhKQUy8K1ABOAEZa0wBRRpS2zLrsgDFGgpq+0wBxRpam9uynboB2WfQASWGktIBdDJBkACcAa2ymJD34uFkoNmUaWTI0UAAPB5AAMxo4QWVslCVMAE8cHBsmw9jdZDoQDt-i93p9vuhEn9AcD0ABHBhIWSYOhqGikKF-NhsQQ4nBGUBwr4-eIAoEgsG3SG1KkIhK0lHZDFYnHqHEErY7K6yd73TQgYgfADuLwgmD2bAOqJA8qxEBwpwumEJdUeNAM4sESCYnwiJNB2QAxE0UmYkrYqvEyHsaAjXjoIHAlEaTYJfDQEHQ0C0AAxhsNpSNAA) that you've provided and it worked for me:

I just changed the label limit to an arbitrary big number like 500

```
"config": {
    "view": {"stroke": "transparent"},
    "axis": {
      "labelColor": "#98A2B3",
      "grid": false,
      "labelLimit": 500
    }
}
```

[image]